# How to write an API test with Polymer iron-ajax

Tags: polymer, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I am trying to generate an `iron-ajax` request and run a test on its response in Polymer 2.x with using the Mocha test suite.

However, when running this test I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'generateRequest' of undefined  Context. at my-test.html:25

```
<!doctype html>

<html> 
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <title>shop-catalogs</title>

  <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/web-component-tester/browser.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/web-component-tester/data/a11ySuite.js"></script>

  <!-- Import the element(s) to test -->
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
  <script src="/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <test-fixture id="ajax">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax
        handle-as="json" 
        headers$='{"Authorization": "Bearer api_access_token"}'
        method="get"
        url="https://api.com/test/endpoint">
      </iron-ajax>
    </template>
  </test-fixture>

  <script>
    suite('shop-catalogs tests', () => {
      var ajax;

      test('checking for AJAX response', () => {

        let request = ajax.generateRequest();
        request.completes.then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })

      });

    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I make an AJAX request and handle the response in this framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice to use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for this. It also will send an ajax call and is native to your browser.

```
<html> 
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <title>shop-catalogs</title>

  <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/web-component-tester/browser.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/web-component-tester/data/a11ySuite.js"></script>

  <!-- Import the element(s) to test -->
  <script src="/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <script>
    suite('shop-catalogs tests', () => {
      test('checking for AJAX response', (done) => {
        fetch("https://api.com/test/endpoint", {
            headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer api_access_token"}
        }).then(res => {
            assert.equal(res.status, 200)
            return res.json()
        })
        .finally(res=>{ 
            console.log(res)
            done()//async test needs to tell when done 
        })
      });

    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you!!

Comment: What is the purpose of chaining two `thens` together?

Comment: None just my coding style :-D

Comment: Do you think of it as, the first then controls the pass / fail and the second then ensures completion?

Comment: Yes i do. I guess even better would be to use finally instead of then for the last then so the test will end even if ajax failed. Also i would do my asserts in the first then block like checking the http status code and if the result is what i expected

Comment: I see. Thank you for the tips! I am new to writing tests, so it's great to get feedback like this :).